# Detect empty lines in a file

Tags: php, file

I have a little script that use the function file() for reading the entire file into an array.

```
$arr = file('file.txt');
```

The file.txt is structured like this:

```
john
david

james
```

So if I debug the array it returns:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(6) "john
"
  [1]=>
  string(7) "david
"
  [2]=>
  string(2) "
"
  [3]=>
  &string(5) "james"
}
```

I'm trying to find a way to detect the empty line when I analyze every value of the array in a foreach loop:

```
foreach ($arr as $value) {
```

I tried with the empty function but nothing.. I also tried with comparing the value with `PHP_EOL` or `\n`, also nothing.

I know that I can avoid empty lines with FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES, but I don't need it. I'm just searching for a way to detect this empty lines.

Comment: What did `empty($value)` return?

Comment: It returns the boolean false

Comment: You can try empty(trim($value));

Comment: Its not an empty line, it has a newline in it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not use `file` directly, it may result in memory problems. In stead try this.

```
<?php
$file = fopen("test.txt","r");

while(! feof($file))
{
   // Trim will remove any whitespace prepended/appended
   // Empty line will now result in empty string
   $line = trim(fgets($file));
}

fclose($file);
```

Comment: The original poster has been using `file()` without any problems, it is irrelevant to the question.

Answer (score 0):

you can `trim()` $value befor you test it with `empty()` like this :

```
if(empty(trim($value)) {
  //  $value is empty
}
```

if it's not working test it with `preg_match()` like this:

```
foreach ($arr as $value) {
   if(preg_match("/(^[\r\n]*|[\r\n]+)[\s\t]*[\r\n]+/", $value)) {
      // $value is empty
   }
}
```

Comment: How about linking the question, then?

Answer (score 0):

Use `trim()` and `continue`:

```
$arr = file('file.txt');

foreach ($arr as $value) {
    if ('' === trim($value)) {
        // line is empty
        continue;
    }

    // process non-empty line here
}
```

For reference, see:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php